# How can I use the Shopify python api adapter to pull assets?

Tags: python, api, shopify

[Shopify Python API on Github](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api)

I am able to get this far and pull in a list of all of the assets, but can't figure out how to actually pull them down from here. Any ideas?

```
SHOP_NAME = "SHOP-NAME"
API_PASSWORD = "API-PASSWORD"
session = shopify.Session(SHOP_NAME)
session.token = API_PASSWORD
shopify.ShopifyResource.activate_session(session)

assets = shopify.Asset.find()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shopify.Asset.find()` is using the [list endpoint](http://api.shopify.com/asset.html#index) which doesn't include the asset value, and it sounds like that is what you are after.

If you use the [receive a single Asset](http://api.shopify.com/asset.html#show) endpoint, then you can also get the assets value.

```
asset = shopify.Asset.find(assets[0].key, theme_id=assets[0].theme_id)
print asset.value
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to figure this out eventually but forgot to post the answer.